# asp.net page flickers

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net webform. I have the background as an image,that when i aslo have a menu bar, when i click on an icon, it uses response.redirect() to redirect to a new page, but when it loads up the page, it seems like the background image is slow.  I can see the backgroud as white first and then split seconds later the background image will load up, this causes an illusion of flickering when it redirects to a new page.  How do i solve this problem? When i tested using visual studio web server, it dont flicker. I am using a background image in the master page hosted up on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You will always end up in this situation, since internet has inherent lag. If you really (can you not remove this image?) need to keep a background image, then consider [Image Slicing](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/webgraphics/a/whyslice.htm). That might solve your issue. HTH.